# how to create an array of 5 elements dynamically and print the sum of all elements in end?

Tags: java

when I try the same logic and execute using for loop it works whereas when I try the same using for each loop it doesn't give the expected result. when I try to print sum of all elements at end it gives the answer 0.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Main
{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter the size of array");
        float n = sc.nextFloat(); float sum=0;
        float []a =new float[5];
        System.out.println("Enter the elements of array");
        for(float element : a)
        {
            element = sc.nextFloat();
        }
        System.out.println("The sum of the items in array are:");
        for(float element : a)
        {
           sum = sum + element; 
           
        }
        System.out.println(sum);
        
    }
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there a way to assign values into an Array with forEach?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59894380/is-there-a-way-to-assign-values-into-an-array-with-foreach)

Answer (score 0):

As pointed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59894380/is-there-a-way-to-assign-values-into-an-array-with-foreach) , you can't do it.
Here is an equivalent way using `while` and array assignment :

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter the size of array");
        int n = sc.nextInt();
        float sum = 0;
        float[] a = new float[n];
        System.out.println("Enter the elements of array");
        int i = 0;
        while (i < n) {
            a[i++] = sc.nextFloat();
        }
        System.out.println("The sum of the items in array are:");
        for (float element : a) {
            sum = sum + element;
        }
        System.out.println(sum);

    }
}
```

Good luck on your path young padawan!

Answer (score 0):

A `float` is a primitive value, so when you're iterating `a` in your loop and assigning each value to `element`, your `element` variable will just receive a copy of the value taken from the array.  It is not a reference to a value inside your array.

Note that even if your array contained Objects instead of primitives, you would still not be able to replace one of them by reassigning a reference variable of that Object to something else.  You could alter the property of a mutable Object in your array using a reference to that object, but you couldn't replace the Object itself.